# How to display the expression without '**' (as exponent) in flask?

Tags: python, flask

For example : integration of a*a will be output as a**3/3. But I want the answer to be a^3/3 or in much readable form by using two lines.
I am using sympy from python to integrate.

Comment: You can produce LaTeX code with `sympy.latex` and have it typeset using [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

Comment: Thanks. I used the replace function. When ever it shows the ** , It just converts it to ^.